# Which (near) realtime spatial database for 1M+ entries?

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, redis, hbase, postgis

I am starting an analytic project which will handle millions of geolocalised datas.
The data will be probably something like this :

`id{
    userId,
    long,
    lat,
    time,
    appId
}`

My main operations :

- get all the data included in a zone
- find all the point belong to a userId
- pub/sub to show all new entries
- add/remove a field on all datas (or just fews)

I would like to use Meteor.js and need near realtime performance (~0,5s to 3s max).

Maybe it is important : I need a precision between 3-15m in my result.

So I looked on :

**Redis :** seams simple to use, there is a Redis Geo plugin. Plus there is a driver for meteor.

**PostGIS :** real time performance with M+ of entries? No driver for meteor.

**PostGre :** there is a driver for meteor.

**Hbase :** seams build for big tables. No driver for meteor.

Which one would you use? (Any other suggestion would be appreciated.)

Comment: Why don't you test it? Postgis should be able to handle this without problems, unless you don't have proper indexes or write really bad queries. And if PostGre is your alias for PostgreSQL, PostGIS is an extension running on PostgreSQL. And don't forget, a million records is next to nothing for a database.

Comment: @FrankHeikensThw for your advice. I am not testing yet because I have no idea what I am doing :) But you have already minimized the possibilities. So thx :)

Comment: If you need access to geographic information, you can try the [SmartyStreets API](https://smartystreets.com/docs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [postgres-client for nodejs](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), this should be useable with meteor. It works like a charm, when it comes to PostGIS (used it myself in some projects). You have to take care of the output though (using postGIS-output-functions (e.g. ST_AsGeoJSON), in combination with ARRAY, while designing your queries).

PostGIS is probably the best choice, when it comes to spatial queries. It is thouroughly tested, properly maintained and is used in many applications.

I can not make any assertions on your performance-constraints though. Spatial queries are inherently complex (e.g: polygon intersection has at best a O(n^2) complexity). You might be able to mitigate performance-issues with indices and caches though. Always worked for me, but i never had to deal with tight query-time constraints.

Regarding you operations: All but the first one should cost next to nothing (database-performance wise). The First query can be a bit tricky, as you will have to use one of the following functions: `ST_Intersects()`, `ST_Contains()` or `ST_Covers()`. All of these have a complexity bigger than O(n). Your queries can be designed, so that it runs quite fast, but as I said: I don't know if your constraints are respected.

Comment: 3ms (if it is not a typo) is fine ! Indeed even 3s is fine. I am looking for **near** real time perf. Have you ever tried the others ones [link]Redis Geo(https://matt.sh/redis-geo#_how-to-add-geo-commands-to-redis) or HBase ?

Comment: Nope I haven't, but Redis Geo sounds interesting enough... It has a very limited set of functions though, and ... yes it was a typo ;-) ... i removed that sentence

Comment: Ok I think I will start with postGis. Regarding the zoning. I think I have an Idea : indeed a zone is predefined because It is a administrative zone. So a point could have a `zoneIdentifierId` (eg : a zip code) set at insertion time regarding where it is. This way I could easily retrieve a zone without the cost of complex functions.

Comment: @DanielN: Yes, you can go that way. It will be definitly faster than intersection or conainment-functions. I would suggest that you try to implement them nevertheless. You can learn a lot, and it can be an eye-opener on how postGIS and spatial databases work.

Comment: Sure I will implement this as well as It would not be time critical. Now I have to find a way to make meteor works with postgis. There is a PostGreSQL package for meteor, I don't know if I can install PostGIS on top of this.